# Java Cucumber passing function to step arguments

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin, feature-file

I have step:
Then date in field: is equal to 'myDate'

usually data-time format data is transferred to this step
but I have a specific case that checks that the date is today, so I cannot hardcode the date

How I can resolve this prombel.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Better way in such case is to handle it inside step. For instance,

`Then date in field: is equal to today`

However, If you are using cucumber version 5+ you can use [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#qaf-cucumber) that will enable features from qaf which allows you to use [properties](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/properties_configuration.html#in-bdd).

Below is example.

```
Then date in field: is equal to '${expr:com.qmetry.qaf.automation.util.DateUtil.getDate(0, 'MM/dd/yyyy')}'
```

Alternately you can have property that store value for today and use that property. For example:
in property file

```
today = ${expr:com.qmetry.qaf.automation.util.DateUtil.getDate(0, 'MM/dd/yyyy')}
```

your step:

```
Then date in field: is equal to '${today}'
```